# How can I highlight a cell and move this cell over 3 columns using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to move a cell value to the right 3 columns and highlight this cell in the process.

I'm able to move a cells contents over 3 columns using the below formula:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(22, lastColAmt).MergeArea: .Cut .Offset(0, 3):
End With
```

I set lastColAmt is equal to the last used column in this row.

However, i'm unable to figure out how to highlight this cell (either prior to moving and then moving with the cell value and highlight or after move to new cell, three columns away but in the same row).

I've tried just adding ".Interior.Color = 65535" or trying to select this cell using another formula but nothing I try moves both the cell value and the highlight. Does anyone know how I can do this?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(22, lastColAmt).Interior.Color = 65535` the line before the With?  That worked for me.